# liquid slider and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the Liquid Slider with ajax and i have a problem with height.

this is my script:

```
var api2 = $.data( $('#slider-7')[0], 'liquidSlider');

  $.ajax({
    complete: function() {

      $('#siteloader').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work1.html');
      $('#siteloader2').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work2.html');
      $('#siteloader3').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work3.html');
      $('#siteloader4').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work4.html');
      api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());

    }

  });
```

The pages are loaded in the div but adjustHeight doesn't work correctly...where is the problem?

Thank's

Comment: What does `api2.getHeight()` return for you?

Comment: it doesn't always work..sometimes when I load page i view html content with wrong height

Comment: Can be a timing issue can you try:setTimeout(function() {
    api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());
}, 500);

Comment: thank's, i ve just tried but nothing..problem remains

Answer (score 0):

That way, simply add this script to your ajax complete function:

```
var innerHeight = $('#innerElement').height();
```

look that [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PabloWeb18/LM7HF/)

So... you can use this code like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    complete: function() {
  $('#siteloader').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work1.html');
  $('#siteloader2').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work2.html');
  $('#siteloader3').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work3.html');
  $('#siteloader4').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('work4.html');
  api2.adjustHeight(true, $(api2).height());
    }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your script but it doesn't work...so i put it in a setTimeout function with an alert, just to try..after load html page alert gave me the height of the page but the "api2.adjustHeight(true, $(api2).height());" doesn't work..

Comment: Try to get HTML ELEMENT and get the heigth using `.height()` function.

Comment: it works, thank you! but now i have another problem...i've tried this: 


  setTimeout(function() { 
  
   var h = $('.innerElement').height();
   
      $("#slider-7").height(h);

   }, 250); 


i put every html pages'container into .innerElement but now height is the same for every content..for example, if i load #siteloader2 its height is the same of #siteloader1...

Comment: So, you must to see what the `api2.adjustHeight(...)`  function returns to you.

Comment: sorry, this function doesn't work in my case...I tried several times but nothing

Comment: This is weird! So does the following, put your code in jsFiddle so I can have a broader vision! by this way I can help you!

Comment: add me at skype **Pablo R. Nunes**

Answer (score 0):

problem solved for me:

```
<pre>



$.ajax({
    complete: function() {
      $('#siteloader').html('<div#siteloader>This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place</div>' + $('.profile').html()).load('work1.html');
      $('#siteloader2').html('<div#siteloader>This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place</div>' + $('.profile').html()).load('work2.html');
      $('#siteloader3').html('<div#siteloader>This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place</div>' + $('.profile').html()).load('work3.html');
      $('#siteloader4').html('<div#siteloader>This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place</div>' + $('.profile').html()).load('work4.html'); 


     setTimeout(function() { 

      var api2 = $.data( $('#slider-7')[0], 'liquidSlider');

          if($().liquidSlider) {
             api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());
          }

      }, 200); 
    }
  });

</pre>
```

I check if liquid slider function exists in setTimeout(function() and "api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());" works.

Thanks, everyone!